# Adding setup time in between tasks of a machine in Google or-tools

Tags: python, or-tools

A new user of Google or-tools here. I ran through the job shop scheduling example in the documentation and would like to try adding setup time to jobs assigned to a machine. How to do that correctly?

First I created a list of tasks to machines

```
for jobId, job in enumerate(jobsdata):
        for taskId, (machine, duration) in enumerate(job):
            machinetasks[machine].append(alltasks[jobId, taskId])
```

I tried

```
m = 0
print(machinelist[0])
for i in range(len(machinetasks[m])-1):
    task = machinetasks[m][i]
    nexttask = machinetasks[m][i+1]
    b = model.NewBoolVar("")
    model.Add(nexttask.start >= task.end + 1000)).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
```

But it doesn't work. If I do

```
m = 0
print(machinelist[0])
for i in range(len(machinetasks[m])-1):
    task = machinetasks[m][i]
    nexttask = machinetasks[m][i+1]
    b = model.NewBoolVar("")
    model.Add(nexttask.start >= task.end + 1000)
```

It adds setup time in between tasks in the stated sequence (i-->j) but won't work for other direction (j-->1).

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't show it in your code, I'm guessing that `machinetasks[m][i]` is an IntervalVar for the ith task on machine m. You appear to be assuming that job `i+1` will be the job following `i` on the machine-- is that always true?. I think you will have to constrain `b` to be true when  job `i+1` follows job `i` and false otherwise.

I suggest trying this:

```
m = 0
print(machinelist[0])
for i in range(len(machinetasks[m])-1):
    task1 = machinetasks[m][i]
    task2 = machinetasks[m][i+1]
    b = model.NewBoolVar("")
    # b will be true when task2 follows task1, false otherwise
    # Now we constrain the relevant start and end to be separated by 1000
    model.Add(task2.start >= task1.end + 1000)).OnlyEnforceIf(b)
    model.Add(task1.start >= task2.end + 1000)).OnlyEnforceIf(b.Not())
```

If b is true, task2 starts 1000 after the end of task1, otherwise task1 starts 1000 after the end of task2.  Since b will always be either true or false, one of the constraints will be enforced and the value for b will emerge as part of the solution.

Comment: or you can look at the this example: https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/examples/python/jobshop_ft06_distance_sat.py

Comment: Thanks very much for helping! Yes, your suggestion seems to work well. Appreciate it